# how to use macrun x in orbbasic to run a macro on sphero

Tags: macros, basic, sphero-api, sphero

I am using orbbasic and macrolab.  I would like to be able to execute macros in orbbasic.  The statement, macrun x, appears to be just what I need.  But I have not been able to figure out how to actually use it.

Is this supposed to run macros that are created in macrolab?  How would I need to set them up?  What ID (parameter x) would I use (macrolab doesn't seem to show any ID)?  I would much appreciate a simple example of: 1.) Create a small test macro. 2.) Create a small orbbasic program that executes this macro using the macrun x command. 3.) Description of step-by-step what extra setup needs to be done to make it work.

I am not working in a development environment at this time.  I have Sphero 2 connected to a Nexus (Android) and have been using only the core 'Sphero' app, macrolab, and orbbasic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more advanced feature that was intended to be used in a development environment along with a SDK. This may work however if you execute the macro you want to run in MacroLab with "temporary chunk" turned off in settings, then launch orbBasic and use "macrun 255".  This should cause it to run the macro stored at address 255 which is where MacroLab will store it if you turn off temporary chunk.